# Is there a way to copy a long Excel table over to Word such that headers repeat?

Tags: excel, ms-word

Basically I want to copy this table over to my main Word document from Excel but then I'd have to manually re-insert all my headers on each page.

Is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Does it help to insert headers only once?

Word 2003: Menu "Table" - "Heading rows repeat".
Word 2010: Menu "Table" - "Table Properties" - "Row" - "Repeat as header row at the top of each page"